# Rspec - test model that has two associations two the same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my app I created friend list for User. Inside Friend model I have validations for unique connection between users. Everything works good, but I don't know how to write tests for this model. It's looks like that:

**Friend.rb**

```
class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user1, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :user2, :class_name => 'User'

  validate :uniqueness_of_users_associations, :cant_be_friend_with_yourself

  def uniqueness_of_users_associations
    unless (user1.friends.where(user2: user2) + user1.is_friend.where(user1: user2)).blank?
      errors.add(:friend, 'He is already your friend')
    end
  end

  def cant_be_friend_with_yourself
    errors.add(:friend, "You can't be friend with yourself") if user1 == user2
  end
end
```

**User.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Devise::Models 

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  has_many :friends, :class_name => 'Friend', :foreign_key => 'user1', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :is_friend, :class_name => 'Friend', :foreign_key => 'user2', dependent: :destroy
end
```

**spec/factories/friends.rb :**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :friend do
    association :user1, factory: :user
    association :user2, factory: :user
    confirmed { true }
  end
end
```

**friend_spec.rb :**

```
RSpec.describe Friend, type: :model do
  describe 'relationships' do
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:user1).class_name('User') }
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:user2).class_name('User') }
  end
end
```

When I try to run test I get error:

```
Failure/Error: unless (user1.friends.where(user2: user2) + user1.is_friend.where(user1: user2)).blank?
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `friends' for nil:NilClass
```

Why I get nil inside model? I did something wrong inside factory?

Comment: I don't think your associations are set up correctly. Surely you should want `user.friends` to be a list of `User` records, not a list of `Friend` records? In your setup, `Friend` is just the JOIN table; probably not something you generally are about referencing directly?

Comment: I would rename the `Friend` model to something like `Relationship`. And I would change the association on `User` to: [`has_many :friends, through: :relationships, ....`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: You can also simplify the validation [using built-in rails functionality](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness): `validates :user1, uniqueness: {scope: :user2, message: 'Users are already friends'}`. (Note: Try to make error messages gender-neutral, unless you actually have information on the gender!!)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will check this, but I have one question to validate that you suggest. For example we have two users Fred and John. When Fred invite John then to JOIN table will be added connection { id: 1, user1: Fred_id, user2: John_id } and because of your validation Fred can't invite again John, but what if John will try to invite Fred? Then connection will be { id: 2, user1: John_id, user2: Fred_id }, so it's different than the first connection. Will your validate catch this? I'm asking, because I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my proposed built-in validation does. It's saying "pairs of values (`user1`, `user2`) must be unique". But by all means, try it and test it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to find if Users 1 & 2 are friends is this query:

```
EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 
 FROM friends
 WHERE 
     friends.user1_id = 1 OR friends.user2_id = 1 
   AND 
     friends.user1_id = 2 OR friends.user2_id = 2
)
```

```
class Friend < ApplicationRecord

  validate :uniqueness_of_users_associations, :cant_be_friend_with_yourself

  def uniqueness_of_users_associations
    if Friend.between(user1.id, user2.id).exists?
      errors.add(:base, 'Friendship already exists')
    end
  end

  def self.between(a, b)
    user1_id, user2_id = arel_table[:user1_id], arel_table[:user2_id]
    where(user1_id.eq(a).or(user2_id.eq(a)))
    .where(user1_id.eq(b).or(user2_id.eq(b))) 
  end
  # ...
end
```

However the naming here is super off. The model should be named `Friendship` as `friend` actually means the person that you are friends with.

Comment: It should be noted though that this will still be prone to race conditions. I would really avoid the "friendfuck" solution with two FKs and create a separate pivot table instead. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Comment: Ok, thanks you for advice. I will check link that u send and try to change my structure

Comment: I don't know if there is any tutorial for the alternative solution but you basically want to create a friendships table and a extra join table with a user id and a friendship id. That avoids the whole "is it a or b?" conundrum and lets you create simpler constraints and assocations that actually work.

Comment: Im not sure I understand this solution. In friendships I will store any information about connection (e.g. { friendship_id: 1, confirmed: true } ) and in join table I will store connection between users and friendships (e.g. { connection_id: 1, user_id: 1, friendship_id: 1}, { connection_id: 1, user_id: 2, friendship_id: 1 } ), so if two users have the same firendship_id then they are already friends. Is that good solution? What you think?

Comment: Yeah thats pretty much it - but without the table name prefixes for the primary keys.

Comment: Yea, I added prefixes to make examples more readable :D Thanks for help! ;)

Comment: My understanding was that the (poorly named) `friends.user1` and `friens.user2` columns stored information on a **DIRECTIONAL** relationship - i.e. "Twitter/Instagram-style", rather than "Facebook-style". If anything, your answer actually highlights the poor naming choice. Perhaps calling it "followers" rather than "friends" would be more descriptive, and regardless, the columns `user1` and `user2` are unnecessarily vague.

Comment: @TomLord a directional relationship is actually a lot easier to model as it doesn't have the same built-in vagueness. While you can improve the naming its still very awkward to do assocations in AR where it can be one of two columns since you can't setup assocations with an OR built into the join.